# ANTLR Grammar for while loop

Tags: antlr, antlr4, antlr3, antlr2

**Hi there,**

I need a C grammar for parsing the while loops. Say, for example, I need to parse the following code:

```
A = 20
B = 1
WHILE(A < 30 )
//function call
A = A + B
ENDWHILE
```

I would require to parse and evaluate the expressions. I have followed some steps and written a grammar, but that is not yielding me the desired output. As per the above code, the function inside the loop has to be called 10 times after the condition check.

Firstly, I'm storing the values of A and B in a hash table (ref : ANTLR_HASH_TABLE struct) and the while rule looks something like this:

```
whileStatement : 'WHILE' condExpr 'ENDWHILE'
               ;
```

I'm able to store and get values from hash table, but I'm stuck with the function call that is to be called/printed those many number of times. I would like to know what steps should be followed to call/print the function that number of times.

Any ideas on how this has to be achieved would be of great help.

Answer (score -1):

For while loops, you could use predicates in ANTLR4.

For the example you posted, you could do something like the following for a while loop:(JAVA target language).

```
grammar SO;

sampleRule
locals [int A, int B]
:
IDENTIFIER1 '=' INTEGER {$A = Integer.parseInt($INTEGER.text);}
IDENTIFIER2 '=' INTEGER {$B = Integer.parseInt($INTEGER.text);}
(
{$A < 30;}? 
IDENTIFIER1 '=' IDENTIFIER1 '+' IDENTIFIER2
{$A = $A + $B;}
)*
;

IDENTIFIER1
: 'A'
;

IDENTIFIER2
: 'B'
;

INTEGER
: [0-9]*
;
```

This grammar is limited to the particular example you have provided but should not be too difficult to extend by using the above grammar.

Comment: Hi rishab,  the above grammar accepts any number of such loops in the input file. But, the while loop need to b parsed until the condition fails, which means I should call the while rule again. How to do this?  If I am correct, should I implement recursive descent parsing method?